# started from command line?

Tags: c++, c, linux

I have a simple C/CPP process running on a linux system. This is a.out.

Another process is capable to start a.out inside its code. This is b.out.

What code do I need inside a.out to understand that it is executed from the command line?
Eg ./a.out

Is there a way a process to know if it started from the cmd or started from another process?

Comment: If it is started from the command line, then it is started from another process (namely the shell).

Comment: preferably your a.out should not care. If it needs to care, implement that logic by either passing a command line argument to it, or call the program by another name (you'd do that by creating a symlink or hardlink to your a.out and your a.out code checks argv[0] for how it was invoked)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would set an environment variable, in the parent process, to some value (say the parent pid), and have the child process check for it.

It is unlikely that a shell user would set this variable (call it something unlikely to name-clash), so if this variable is set to the expected value, then you know that it is being started from the parent process.

Answer (score 6):

You can't find out in general whether a program was started "from the command line" (by a user's explicit command), but you can find out whether its standard input and output are talking to a terminal/command window:

```
#include <unistd.h>
isatty(fileno(stdin))
```

and `stdout` return whether standard input/standard output are terminals.

If you need to know what process starting your program, use the [`getppid`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getppid.html) system call to get the parent's process ID (ppid), then read the pseudo-file `/proc/`*ppid*`/cmdline`.

Comment: If you use isatty, you'll get false for redirection at the command line. As a user, I'd be upset by a command I can't use in pipes...

Comment: The correct answer depends critically on what the OP wants to do. I just listed some options. (Maybe it should only behave *differently* for terminals, e.g. give a prompt?)

Comment: All the implementations of `ls` I've used try putting filenames into columns when called from the terminal, but have one file per line when piping output.

Comment: @David Thornley, +1 for the example, Apparently, you've never used 4.3BSD or earlier :)

Comment: 4.3 was pretty current when I was introduced to Unix, but I don't know that I ever worked on an actual BSD (until Mac OSX, which hardly counts).  SunOS, Solaris, HP-UX, AIX, Tru64, a few different Linux OSes....nope.

Answer (score 2):

You can check its parent task ID, using `getppid()`

Answer (score 2):

You can do multiple things, but none will be 100% reliable:

- `isatty(0)` to check whether standard input is a TTY terminal,
- check for the parent task ID (`getppid()`), then lookup the parent's PID to match it against its executable's path (using whatever you want. a call to `ps` and some parsing could do, or have fun using `/proc/`)
- you could also just have a look at the environment variables set up. do a printout of all the values contained in the env. To do that, either use the extern `environ` variable:

  `extern char **environ;`
- or modify your `main()` prototype to be:

  `int main(int ac, char **av, char **environ)`

Comment: `getenv` is the preferred way to read the environment. How does the environment help?

Comment: yes, you could do that as well, but `getenv` requires you to know which key you want to read. So that could be usefull, or you may want to go through the whole thing. For the rest, sorry if I wasn't being clear enough: you could look for the differences on some particular variables (SHELL, DISPLAY...). There'll be minor differences between different kinds of execution as well. I am actually on windows right now so I cannot really try this out but I did something like that a while back. But like I said, it's not 100% reliable. Definitely not.

Comment: @larsmans: actually, come to think of it, what I was doing back then was trying to determine if my program was being executed through an SSH connection or not, but that's how I did (unreliably) determine it.

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether its standard input is a terminal:

```
if(isatty(0)) { ... }
```

Comment: Keep in mind you'd only benefit from this if a.out gets its stdin redirected, otherwise it'll just inherit the stdin of b.out, which is a tty.

Answer (score 0):

In short: you can't doing it directly.
In long: look you can check the `getppid()` value and compare it with the `bash` PID or`b.out` PID
TO search for a process inside the process table with Known PID with C  you can do this:

1) get the `PPID` of `a.out` and search with this value in `/porc` and then if you find the folder check the `cmdline` file and check if this process is `b.out` or `shell` process.

2) you can deal with `sysctl` system call and dealing with kernel param's(you can google it)

3)
     `pid_t ppid = getppid();

     system("pidof bash > text.in");`

the `system` will get the pid of any shell process and write the result to  `text.in` file
it contains all bash PID's space separated you can compare this values with `getppid()` value.
Good Luck.